# replacing lines with different values in text file in python

Tags: python

I have a big text file like the small example:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
```

I am trying to make something like this:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
12.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
5.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
50.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
```

each text file is followed by some number lines. as you see in the output I want to replace the first number of each group by sum of all numbers which are below the same text line(in the same group) and replace the rest of them by 1.000000.
and write in into a new file.

I actually tried the following code in python but did not return what I was looking for:

```
infile = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in infile:
    if line startswith"fit":
        for l in len(line):
            line[l] = line + line[l+1]
```

Comment: just to confirm that you have 3 files here each containing a group? your output is to one file or to 3 separate files? I am not sure because you said `each text file is followed by some number lines.`

Comment: if each of your file contains only one group (i.e. each file is followed by number lines), then you can generate the result with far less codes using pandas with output to each file. even if you want to combine them into one big file afterwards, it's easy. But I am not sure if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither the most elegant nor the most efficient way to implement it, but it might give you some insight about what you need to do:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as infile:

    tempList = []        #Auxiliary list for number storage
    sums = []            #Stores the numbers of each fit heading
    fits = []            #Stores the 'fit' headings
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
        if not line.find("fit")==-1:
            fits.append(line)
            sums.append(tempList)
            tempList = []
        else:
            tempList.append(float(line.replace("\n","")))
            print(tempList)
    sums.append(tempList)
    sums.remove([])


for i in sums:
    i[0] = sum(i[0:])
    for j in range(1,len(i)):
        i[j] /= i[j]

print(fits)
print(sums)

with open("test2.txt", "w") as outFile:

    for i in range(len(fits)):
        outFile.write(fits[i])
        outFile.write("\n".join(str(j) for j in sums[i]))
        outFile.write("\n")
```

The output file `test2.txt` contains the following:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
12.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
5.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
50.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Dictionary to store the "header" line as key
# And values will be the "sublines" you are changing
groups = {}

# First, get positions of "fit" lines
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('fit'):
            current = line # the current "header" ("fit" line)
            groups[current] = []
        else:
            # Need to convert from 'str' to 'float'
            groups[current].append(float(line.strip()))

# Now sum and pad with 1.0
for header in groups:
    # Fill with 1.0 by adding 2 lists
    # First list is length 1 and contains only the sum of the original
    # Second list is length first - 1 and is all 1.0
    groups[header] = [sum(groups[header])] + [float(1)] * (len(groups[header]) - 1)

# Then rewrite to file
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for header in groups:
        f.write(header) # May need to add a '\n' if not present in file orignally
        for num in groups[header]:
            # Convert 'float' back to 'str' with newline
            f.write('{!s}\n'.format(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using `itertools` modules `groupby` and `chain` + list comprehension

```
infile = open("file.txt", "r")
from itertools import groupby,chain
list_grp = [list(g) for k,g in groupby([i.strip() for i in infile.readlines()], lambda x:'fit' in x)]
for i in chain(*[[i[0]] if 'fit' in i[0] else list(chain(*[[sum(map(float,i))],[1.0 for i in i]])) for i in list_grp]):
    print (i)
```

Output:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
12.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
5.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
50.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this using pandas as well:

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

def is_float(x):
    try:
       float(x)
       return True
    except ValueError:
       return False

def to_float(x):
    if is_float(x):
       return float(x)
    else:
       return x

data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, converters={0:to_float}) # line 1
is_numeric_value = lambda x: not is_float(x)
condition = data[0].map(is_numeric_value)
```

**Main**

```
titles = data.loc[condition]
title_count = len(titles.index) # count of titles

for i in xrange(title_count):
      ind = titles.index[i]
      if (i+1) != len(titles.index):
          next_ind = titles.index[i+1]
          data.iat[ind+1,0]=data.iloc[ind+2:next_ind].values.sum()
      else:
          data.iat[ind+1,0]=data.iloc[ind+2:].values.sum() # line 2
```

**Output**

```
      c5d.to_csv(file_path, header=None, index=False) # line 3
```

you could convert csv file to txt by replacing .csv with .txt apparently.

P.S. this is under the assumption that you have a big file containing multiple sections (each section being title + number lines); if you have one section in one file, then you can replace above with line #1, #2 and #3, apart from `is_float` and `to_float`.